# Is it possible to apply_filter on a wp_ajax_ action?

Tags: filters, actions

I'm extending someone else's plugin with an AddOn and register it on their 'AddOn' page with an apply_filters .... (if possible)

Their plugin works with Ajax calls on plugin page admin, so when I click on 'AddOn' page it makes an ajax call called 'wp_ajax_checkAddons', which executes a function (that takes no arguments) and gerenates the page HTML.

The question is: Is it possible to hook with apply_filters or add_filters on their function, manipulate it adding HTML to that page?

Exmaple code:

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin-ajax.php',
    data: 'action=checkAddons',
    success: function (response) {
      $('.box').html(response);
    }
  });
```

The action:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_checkAddons', array(&$this, 'checkAddons'));
```

The callback:

```
function checkAddons() {
$result = theClass::theFunction();
die($result);
```

}

The function:

```
class theClass{
public static function theFunction(){
//code
return $code;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: Is it possible to hook with apply_filters or
>   add_filters on their function, manipulate it adding HTML to that page?

`apply_filters` and `add_filter()` do two separate things. `apply_filters` allows a value to be filtered *by* `add_filter()`. This means that if the original code is 3rd-party, you can only use `add_filter()` if that code already has `apply_filters()` applied to it. If you're extending another plugin, you will be using `add_filter()`, *not* `apply_filters()`.

So you need to check if the original `checkAddons` function includes any filters for you to use, by seeing if it uses `apply_filters()` anywhere. If it does, then you can filter the value passed to it with `add_filter()`. If the filter is properly supported, then ideally the original developer has documented it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob for the answer. I'll mark it as correct. There is no apply_filters anywhere on the code, so I can not change it. Thank you again.